# Display Image next to HABTM checkboxes

Tags: cakephp, has-and-belongs-to-many

Cane Somebody give me an ideas on this Please!

I Generate multiple checkboxes from a table that is related with another table with HABTM relationship association. 
I would like to generate multiple checkboxes with an image along with the text in the label.

My two tables are **items** and items_characteristics. So an Item HasAndBelongToMany characteristics, and an ItemCharacteristic HasAndBelongToMany Items.

```
echo $this->Form->input('Item.ItemCharacteristic',array(
    'label' =>false,
    'type'=>'select',
    'multiple'=>'checkbox',
    'options' => $itemCharacteristics ,
    'selected' => $this->Html->value('ItemCharacteristic.ItemCharacteristic')
));
```

This code generate the list of the checkboxes properly and works perfect:
This is what i have:
[image]

Which is generated from DB from the table items_characteristics.

And this is what i wanna have:

[image]

Does Anyone have any Idea how i can achieve this Please?

Comment: I don't think it's possible using formHelper::input options array. You have to loop through the ItemCharacteristics and create the checkboxes with the images inside .

Comment: @arilia And how can i do that but in the same time keep the HABTM relationship between tables?

Comment: Each checkbox should have a unique ID. A CSS/Jquery solution might simplify this considerably, as the images probably aren't *essential* to your app. `...for each(checkbox) append <img src="/img/icon-CheckboxID.jpg"/>...`

Comment: @Ross No images aren't essential. They are just for a better front-end UI that's all. CakePHP generate unique ID for each checkbox, and each checkbox has it's picture path stored in DB. and thats why i want to assign each check box it's corresponding image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume that in your controller you did something like:

```
$this->request->data = $this->Item->find('first',  ... );
```

so that `$data` contains the information about selected characteristics in form of a subarray,

**edit:** I also assume that `Item` habtm `ItemCharacteristic`

then in your view

```
$checked_characteristics = Hash::extract($this->data, 'ItemCharacteristic.{n}.id');
foreach($itemCharacteristics  as $id => $itemCharacteristic )
{
    $checked = in_array($id, $checked_characteristics );
    $img = $this->Html->image('cake.icon.png'); // put here the name 
                                                // of the icon you want to show
                                                // based on the charateristic 
                                                // you are displayng
    echo $this->Form->input(
        'ItemCharacteristic.ItemCharacteristic.', 
        array(
            'between' => $img, 
            'label' => $itemCharacteristic, 
            'value' => $id,  
            'type' => 'checkbox',
            'checked' => $checked
        )
    );
}
```

edit: from your comment I understand that `$itemCharacteristics` come from a `find('list'`) statement.

change it into a `find('all', array('recursive' => -1));`

now your code becomes

```
foreach($itemCharacteristics  as $itemCharacteristic )
{
    $id = $itemCharacteristic['ItemCharacteristic']['id'];
    $icon_name = $itemCharacteristic['ItemCharacteristic']['icon_name']; //or wherever you get your icon path
    $img = $this->Html->image($icon_name); 
    $itemCharacteristicName = $itemCharacteristic['ItemCharacteristic']['name'];
    // same as above
}
```

Comment: Your code works great, but still i cant get to take the icon_path image as i debug it it had only the id and title for each characteristics, and YES item HABTM ItemCharacteristics and vice-versa...